# EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection. header is set to text/event-stream

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

Hi I get This error in my console using sse

EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.

js code is :

```
if (typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") 
{
    var source = new EventSource("../api/updateWellData.php?uid=<?php echo $node_id ?>");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        var response = JSON.parse(event.data);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = response.test;
        // some code like the above line
    };
}  
else 
{
    // refresh the page every 30 secs
}
```

The PHP Code is :

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");

require_once("../resources/config.php");

if (isset($_GET['uid']))
{
    $uid = $_GET['uid'];
    while (1) 
    {
        $query = Query("SELECT * FROM well_data_last WHERE well_detail_id = $uid");
        $result = fetch_array($query);
        echo json_encode($result);
        ob_end_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

This is my first time using sse I used the following documents : [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) | [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp)

Comment: I am having same issue in laravel setup. Some solutions said remove white spaces in php. But that did not resolved my issue.

Comment: Share the exact output from the webserver as-is, including headers and response body.

Answer (score 5):

## This error occurs when your PHP code outputs text in the wrong format.

This may be either a PHP error message (all of which are outputted as raw HTML), or some other text on the page which does not fit [the `text/event-stream` format](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#server-sent-events-intro).

If the output of the PHP file does not match the format required by `text/event-stream`, it will fall back to using `text/html`. Javascript requires event streams use the `text/event-stream` content type so the JS console will show an error, but this is just a symptom of the actual problem - to fix the issue you need to fix your PHP.

---

In OP's case, the issue is with their `echo` statement. All data outputted to the stream must be proceeded by `data:`, and ended with a newline `\n`. The stream itself must end with another newline to indicate that no more `data:` messages follow.

To fix the error, OP should change

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

to

```
echo "data: " . json_encode($result) . "\n\n";
```

---

Another issue with OP's code is that there is no protection against SQL-injection in the database query. While this is irrelevant to the issue at hand, it is worth pointing out that prepared statements should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem and the problem was a syntax error in the php file which showed an error message.

Comment: no my `php` worked fine, I had problems with the `JavaScript`